# Apply Tax refund To Next Year

Tags: taxes

My husband sold inherited property in 2019.  We are filing our 2018 return.  We have about a $2,000 refund.  Should we apply this to our 2019 tax return?

Comment: That would be like making a tax payment an entire year early.  You'd miss out on interest you'd earn if that money were kept in a savings account until you file 2019 taxes.

Comment: How long was it between the inheritance and the sale of the property? If the basis was stepped up at death, you may have very little gain. Also letting us know the country can be a big help.

Comment: Country Tag absolutely required!

Comment: It depends.  (I'm assuming you're in the US.)  If your usual income is mostly wages (or SS, IRA withdrawals, &c) where you have tax withheld on a W2 or similar, then no.  As previously noted, you're just giving the government an interest-free loan.  OTOH, if you make estimated tax payments, then applying the $2000, or as much of it as would match your 1st quarter payment, saves you from having to send in money while waiting for the refund of the $2000. (Especially if you file near the deadline, as it seems you're doing :-))

Comment: @BenVoigt At current big bank rates, I'm sure they won't miss out on that 60 cents.

Comment: @user71659: That is a risk, but other major banks would be paying about $50 total in interest on $2000 for 13 months.